# Convert a base-10 number into a number of any other base

Tags: code-golf, base-conversion, conversion

You have to take a base-10 number (e.g. 735) and another number for the base to convert to, and convert the base-10 number into the equivalent number in the other base.

**Rules:**

- You aren't allowed to use any conversion functions built into your language

This is code-golf, the shortest answer in bytes wins!

Comment: How do you propose dealing with bases above, say, 62? Do we just follow the ASCII chart for symbol progression? Could use some more clarification.

Comment: The _number_ will be the same, only expressed in another base. Can you give a few examples including output?